# Unable to mount secondary hard drive

Tags: mount, fstab

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu (64-bit). And now I have realized that I am unable to mount any partition of my secondary hard drive. I'm getting this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/klemen/Local Disc:  
  Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/klemen/Local Disc"'  
  exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).  
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option
```

I need to mention that I was able to navigate in those partitions right after the Ubuntu installation and now, after 2 hours I am unable to mount them again. So obviously it is my fault. But the only potential harmful installation that I did was installing the AMD Catalyst driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Windows 8 still somehow protect or mount partition when it just get restarted. When I shut down Windows and boot Ubuntu from beginning it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3
```

But it will be more safe to boot into the Windows safe mode and do a clean shutdown.